# SSAS Calculated Measure for computing average

Tags: ssas, mdx

I am trying to compute an average in SSAS based on the following logic.

```
CREATE MEMBER CURRENTCUBE.[Measures].[Avg Institutional Award - Net Confirmed]
 AS case
    when ISEMPTY([Measures].[Net Confirmed Count]) or [Measures].[Net Confirmed Count]=0 then null     
    else [Measures].[Institutional Award]/[Measures].[Net Confirmed Count] end, 
FORMAT_STRING = "#,0;(#,0)", 
VISIBLE = 1;
```

I want to compute the average of the measure "Institutional Award" only if the measure "Net Confirmed Count" is not EMPTY or 0. The problem is that the calculation includes the correct number of "Net Confirmed Count"s but includes all the "Institutional Award" regardless of what  "Net Confirmed Count" is (it could be empty, 0 or 1).

Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would replace your CASE statement with an MDX Divide Function:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj873944.aspx

Comment: Thanks. But I am using SQL Server 2008 R2 and it looks like the Divide function only applies to 2012 and 2014.

Comment: So your choices are: 1. upgrade to the current version or 2. waste more time writing and testing custom code to work around a problem that has already been solved.